# Python path error when running Kolla ansible installation

Tags: ansible, openstack, pythonpath, kolla-ansible

I am attempting to install kolla-ansible to a bare metal server and experiencing this issue. I have been following this guide for setup: https://kifarunix.com/deploy-all-in-one-openstack-with-kolla-ansible-on-ubuntu-18-04/ and have hit a roadblock with an error concerning where the all-in-one file is tested with the line: `kolla-ansible -i all-in-one prechecks`. After running this line I receive the warning and error listed below.[Here is the warning which appears when trying to precheck the setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Opp.png)

After, the precheck fails because of the python path which was specified earlier. [Here you can see the precheck failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEb8J.png) and will not run when I go to deploy it.

What can I do to change the path so that the precheck and deployment will run? The only small issue I can see is that I am following a guide on an Ubuntu 18 OS, and I am using Ubuntu 20, but I did not think that would make a big difference. Any input I could get on this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its about virtual enviroment.

can you try `python3 -c 'import docker'` inside your venv and outside.if both says no module named check `pip list` try reinstall docker outside your venv.